# Nested IF Statements

Tags: code, order, nested

We are moving to use X-Author to upload our planner information into Salesforce via their excel app. The excel spreadsheet has been set up prior and fields are pretty fixed. We are trying to map their status field but where ours was text values the Planner excel is 1,2,3,4 so I was trying to create a IF statement i.e.

```
IF ( Order_Status__c = 1, "Pseudo Machines – not sold", 
IF ( Order_Status__c = 2, "Sale Confirmed – waiting for spec",
IF ( Order_Status__c = 3, "Spec complete – BOM creation",
IF ( Order_Status__c = 4, "BOMs complete – procurement", 
IF ( Order_Status__c = 5, "Production orders released", 
IF ( Order_Status__c = 6, "Assembly Started", 
IF ( Order_Status__c = 7, "Shipping", 
IF ( Order_Status__c = 8, "Installation started", 
IF ( Order_Status__c = 9, "Complete – awaiting sign off",  
OR (Order_Status__c = 10, "Fully paid and signed off", "Please see Admin"
          ))))))))))
```

Not working. It is just a text field Order Status.

Comment: r u doing this in a formula field or workflow field update or apex code ?

Comment: It is supposed to be a picklist value, and ideally just a IF else scenario. I have it as a formula field now as picklist was not suited.

Comment: @iamjury use ISPICKVAL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE) function and try something like this

```
CASE ( Order_Status__c ,
    1, "Pseudo Machines – not sold", 
    2, "Sale Confirmed – waiting for spec",
    3, "Spec complete – BOM creation",
    4, "BOMs complete – procurement", 
    5, "Production orders released", 
    6, "Assembly Started", 
    7, "Shipping", 
    8, "Installation started", 
    9, "Complete – awaiting sign off",  
    10, "Fully paid and signed off", 
    "Please see Admin"
)
```

Comment: Is this for the picklist value or for formula? just trying to make sure.

Comment: its for the formula field.

Comment: I used ISPICKVAL however snippet below. I get error message 

IF(OR(ISPICKVAL( Order_Status__c , "1"), FormulaField   = "1"), 'Pseudo Machines – not sold',
IF(OR(ISPICKVAL( Order_Status__c , "2"), FormulaField = "2"), 'Sale Confirmed – waiting for spec',
IF(OR(ISPICKVAL( Order_Status__c , "3"), FormulaField = "3"), 'Spec complete – BOM creation', 
IF(OR(ISPICKVAL( Order_Status__c , "4"), FormulaField = "4"), 'BOMs complete – procurement',

Comment: Error: Field FormulaField does not exist. Check spelling.

But not sure what to put in there. Its a validation rule, based off a picklist (boss likes those)